# How to correctly write data in Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a method in which I write data in Realm:

```
public void setChatsList(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {
    Realm realm = null;

    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chatsModel);
            }
        });

    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And I read the data from the database in this method:

```
ChatsModel getAllChatsList() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<ChatsModel> chatsModelResult = realm.where(ChatsModel.class).findAll();

    ChatsModel chatsModel = chatsModelResult.get(0);

    return chatsModel;
}
```

When I use the `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` method to write to the database, it does not save. That is, when you get data in the method, `getAllChatsList()` returns 0.

And when I write using the `insertOrUpdate()` method, each time it writes, it does not update an existing record but writes it next to the previous one even if they have the same data

Why the number of entries increases. Although the same object. Well, if there was a list, but I have only one object and to get the last record I do this:

```
ChatsModel chatsModel = chatsModelResult.get(chatsModelResult.size() - 1);
```

Why? Can not I just read without sending an argument - `chatsModelResult.size() - 1`?

**Question**: How can I solve the problem of writing and reading?

Comment: You can check the realm example with all the operations.  https://github.com/maraj91/RealmQueryDemo

Comment: is the `getAllChatesList()` called from a different thread? Try to add `realm.refresh()` in the function before reading. If that is the problem, please take a look at this article https://academy.realm.io/posts/threading-deep-dive/

Comment: @beeender easily possible considering he opens Realm instance that he never closes

Answer (score 1):

```
ChatsModel getAllChatsList() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // <-- realm instance never closed
    RealmResults<ChatsModel> chatsModelResult = realm.where(ChatsModel.class).findAll();

    ChatsModel chatsModel = chatsModelResult.get(0);

    return chatsModel;
}
```

By opening unclosed Realm instances, on non-looper background threads, your version will be retained on an older version of Realm and won't be able to update itself.

A possibility would be proper lifecycle management, or calling `realm.refresh()`.